# What is wrong with this union type in this react component props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a Grid component that can be a container or a item. To achieve this, I can add a prop `container: boolean`. But I also want to add more types when `container` is true.

```js
interface ExtendedProps {
    cols?: Areas
    rows?: Areas
    gap?: Spacing
}
```

Then add these types

```js
type GridProps = {
    container?: false;
    children: ReactNode;
};

type ContainerProps = Omit<GridProps, 'container'> & ExtendedProps & {
  container: true;
};
```

But when I type the props, typescript gives me an error:

```js
export default function Grid({
    container,
    children,
    gap, // Property 'gap' does not exist on type 'GridProps | ContainerProps'.
    cols, // Property 'cols' does not exist on type 'GridProps | ContainerProps'.
    rows, // Property 'rows' does not exist on type 'GridProps | ContainerProps'.
}: ContainerProps | GridProps) {
    // ...
}
```

Why does this happen?

For some reason, when I create an object with type `GridProps | ContainerProps` I get the intended behaviour:

```js
const testObject: ContainerProps | GridProps = {
    children: <div />,
    container: false,
    gap: 2 // error: not assignable
}

const anotherTestObject: ContainerProps | GridProps = {
    children: <div />,
    container: true,
    gap: 2
}
```

You can see this live [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-currying-zpy2ex?file=%2Fsrc%2FGrid.tsx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. If `container` was `false` the other field would not exist

You can get the other fields by checking the `container` first

```
export default function Grid(props: ContainerProps | GridProps) {
  if (props.container) {
    const {
      container,
      children,
      gap,
      cols,
      rows
    } = props

  }
  return <div></div>;
}
```

Comment: For some reason I thought `gap`, `cols` and `rows` would be `undefined` when `container` was `false`, then I checked it later (`container && gap` for example), but the error was still there. Anyway, it works now, thank you!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but they are probably `never` which disallows accessing them